# dbt restart with defer state picks only last run and ignores previous aborts

Tags: command-line, restart, dbt

Currently we need to run two independent set of models at same time , I am currently looking into restartability for these two independent of each other as they will be monitored by separate teams.if both models abort restart picks only last one from runresults.json

Here is my current solution to restart both parallelly

dbt run --select +modelset2 --target-path .\target\modelset2

dbt run --select +modelset1 --target-path .\target\modelset1

for restartability

dbt run --select result:error --defer --state .\target\modelset2

dbt run --select result:error --defer --state .\target\modelset1

Is this a correct approach ..

Comment: I think you probably want separate projects, if the two sets of models are truly independent?

Comment: These are projects which does a duck tape job with multiple independent set of models catering to different needs . most users in dbt are migrating from etl to elt world. Having different project for each independent set would blow up the number of projects... Which is where we are trying to find a way to balance things..